# Qual a diferença entre memmove() e memcpy()?

Tags: c, c++, memória

Qual a diferença entre a função `memmove()` e `memcpy()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O nome [`memmove()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) dá uma ideia um pouco errada já que ela copia igual à [`memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy), então se de fato quiser que o conteúdo se mova precisará apagar o anterior por conta própria. Quase sempre usará a segunda função que é mais rápida e faz o serviço bem.

A primeira difere pela capacidade de sobrepor o conteúdo, ou seja, você pode jogar o conteúdo para um local que pega uma parte dele próprio, por exemplo jogar um conteúdo mais pra frente para abrir espaço para colocar novos dados, então obviamente a cópia precisa ocorrer ao contrário, afinal se copiar na ordem normal um conteúdo irá apagar algo que ainda precisa ser copiado. Obviamente que é preciso um controle maior para fazer isto certo. Uma implementação boa pode otimizar se não for necessário, mas haverá um custo para decidir, se fosse outra linguagem poderia só usar esta função, mas em C isto é um custo inapropriado, afinal ela existe para ser tão rápida quanto possível em todas as circunstâncias.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).